# 2D Tile Engine (World Generation) - Beginner

Tags: java

I am a beginning Java Game Developer. For my first game, I'm making something along an advanced version of [Minicraft](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ld48/ld22/index.html)
by Notch. However I have absolutely clue how to make a 2D Tile-Based World Generator.

Would anyone mind explaining how I would do this and maybe a link or two to some YouTube Videos?

I am using Eclipse EE for Java Developers.

Also I can't seem to resize my window to make the pixels larger. The image is 16 x 16 pixels, however I'd like to display it larger like minicraft (link above)

Here is the code for Skeleton.java (which is the framework ('Skeleton') of the game)`

```
 package code;

 import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Skeleton extends Loop{ //Should extend Applet?
public void init(){
Thread th= new Thread(this);
th.start();
offscreen = createImage(120,160); // 120, 160
d = offscreen.getGraphics();
addKeyListener(this); //15:43
}
public static final int HEIGHT = 120; //Original Height/Width= "120 x 160"
public static final int WIDTH = 160;
public static final String TITLE= "Test Game BETA";
public static final int SCALE = 3;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
d.clearRect(0, 0, 160, 120); //Error Here, Scale perhaps? -Disregard //0,0,160,120      
d.drawImage(him, x, y, this);     //12:17 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmRD0PlAXEY
g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
}
public void update(Graphics g){
    paint(g);
} //Finished at 15:33 ERROR w/ the circle -Fixed
   } 
   //2D Tile Engine Must be Created
```

Comment: Please don't forget to click on the link!

Comment: pixels are based on the display density.  You cant really make a pixel *larger* persay.  ALSO:  for game maps that are random, you will also want to make an algorithm for likelihood of the adjancent blocks to be a different type.  you like, like 80% chance that dirt is next to dirt with a 5% chance that stone is next to dirt.  That way your map isnt random, but infact has a flow about it.

Comment: JAVA IS NOT JAVASCRIPT!!!

Comment: Everything I have learned about 2D world gen, I learned from RogueBasin.  Here is a nice set of articles on the topic: http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Category:WorldGeneration

Comment: I know its not javascript, but unfortunately I accidentally clicked it, sorry.

Comment: I know it's not 2D, but take a look at Infinite Mario Bros since the main point of this project was level generation: http://mojang.com/notch/mario/

Comment: Please format your code (ctrl+shift+F in Eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project that is almost identical to this. The way I generate the worlds, I have a two-dimensional array of tiles, and a method that populates the array with tiles. The way the world is generated, I place a grass tile in each column, followed by a randomly determined number of dirt tiles, followed by stone tiles until the bottom of the world. Then, for the next column, I place a grass tile at a y-coordinate that is between -2 and +2 tiles from the previous grass's y-coordinate, and fill the rest of the column as before. Continue until you get to the end of the array.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and I'll try to do the same, roughly anyway.

Comment: For ores you can do an random coordinates below what ever level you want and then use more random numbers determine wether or not the vein  spreads on.

Answer (score 0):

To rescale images, I use this method

```
public void drawRezizedImage(Graphics g, Image image, int x, int y, int sizeX, int sizeY){

    image.getScaledInstance(200, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

}
```

This will simply draw a rescaled version of your, in this case 16 by 16px image.
Hope this was, what you were looking for.