# Cellular Automata Java (Beginner)

Tags: java, cellular-automata

I'm creating a game along the lines of [Minicraft](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ld48/ld22/index.html). I posted a question about how I should make a terrain similar to the one in the game [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981317/2d-tile-engine-world-generation-beginner) and user by the name of [Quirliom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1702990/quirliom) posted an answer referring to what is called cellular automata.

I had absolutely no clue what it was, let alone how to do it. I did look it up and see what it was. But I have yet to find out how to do it. Could somebody please explain how to do it and how it works, perhaps a link or two or even some source codes/ examples.

Comment: I know I look rather clueless, as I am. 
But, I'm learning it. Slowly but steadily. 

It seems a bit too complex for me, but nonetheless I will attempt to do it anyway.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am attempting to generate a world along the lines of Notches "Minicraft"

Answer (score 0):

For the theory, check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book:Cellular_Automata. Once you have a sense of what cellular automata are in general, the next step is finding sources on their application to landscape generation (a pretty non-standard but not unheard of use); I suspect the initial theory readthrough will give you a pretty good sense on implementation techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, cellular automata are a subclass of dynamical system where space and time are discrete.

Depending on the model considered, some properties may or may not apply:

- The component of the model are connected by a regular graph that is invariant by translation, rotation, etc.
- Given `S` the state space, the updating rule is a function `F(S^n) -> S` where `S^n` is given by the neighborhood of a cell.
- The updating rule is the same for all component.
- The updating rule apply to all cells simultaneously, building states `t+1` from states `t`.

Generally, cellular automata are good models to simulate a dynamical environment  (sand, brownian motion, wildfires) because they allow large size and computation speed, due to their extreme simplicity.

If you want an entry in the world of cellular automata, I recommend you look up the Game of Life by Conway, find a tutorial and implement it.